# Forms: How to implement a conditional tab-keystroke between 2 controls

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have 2 controls (control1, control2; combo boxes) where the second combo box is conditional on the value contained in the first one.

The rules are
For a set of given values in control1; control2 is not enabled.
For a set of other values in control1; control2 is enabled.

I am trying to implement this behaviour:
With focus on control1, when the user is pressing tab we evaluate if control2 must be enabled or disabled, if control2 is enabled it gets the focus, if control2 is not enabled, control3 gets the focus.

I've attempted to use various events on control1 and control2 but it seems to always miss a beat... using control1_Exit I don't seem to be able to prevent it from jumping to control3 even if control2 should be enabled (I've tried to force the focus to control2 but the cursor lands on control3 anyway, seems that when Exit is triggered the cursor is already in transit to control3).

I am scratching my head with this problem for a few hours though it should be a simple one, and searching SE or the web does not seem to lead to a solution... Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to set `control2.Enabled` in the **`On Change`** event of control1. Plus on `Form_Current`, so that it is set correctly for existing data.

Then just set the tab order so that control2 is after control1, and you don't need any code for focus or exit. If control2 is enabled, it receives the focus on tab, if not it won't.